# RegEx expression to replace /randomword/ with <i>randomword</i>?

Tags: regex, text-editing

I'm looking for a RegEx expression to use with Find & Replace that will turn

```
/randomword/
```

into

```
<i>randomword</i>
```

without actually changing the random word. Possible to do this with a sentence also?

Another possibility: Replace a / followed by a letter to  *and a letter followed by a / to*  without replacing the letter in either case. Just the slashes.

**Solutions**

```
FIND: /(\w+)/ REPLACE: <i>\1</i>
```

works in most cases.

```
FIND: /(\w+\.)/ REPLACE: <i>\1</i>
```

works for words that are followed by a period.

```
FIND: /(\w+\?)/ REPLACE: <i>\1</i>
```

works for words that are followed by a question mark.

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't the type of website where you simply ask for somebody else to write a regular expression to do something specific.

Comment: I don't think it's a very specific question. It's a syntax problem. I know /[a-z]/ would cover a random letter. How to expand that to cover an entire word in the middle of a couple of slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like (warning not tested) this for the search:

```
/(\w*)/
```

Which should give you the word - depends on what version of which regex tool you are using as to how you use that.

Comment: This works for the first part of my question. It finds all the words in my document that are preceded and trailed by slashes. Any idea how to turn the slashes into <i>*</i>?

Comment: I figured it out. Put this in your answer if you would: <i>\1</i> Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is one way. As I said, it depends because each application has it's own syntax for replacements. Glad you worked it out.